# Deducing that $x^{12}+x^{4}-x^{3}-x+1\gt 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math

I am trying to find the domain of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{12}+x^{4}-x^{3}-x+1}$. So that requires solving the inequality $x^{12}+x^{4}-x^{3}-x+1\ge 0$. It turns out the domain is $\mathbb{R}$. How to go about proving this. Taking the derivative is rather tedious and does not do much benefit. Factoring is not obvious. $(x^4+1)(x^{8}-x^{4}+1)+(x^{4}-x^{3}-x)\ge 0$. Also tried pairing by adding and subtracting $x^{i}$ for $i\in [1,11]\cap \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ but to no avail.

Any hints on how to proceed are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
x^{12}+x^4-x^3-x+1=x^{12}+(x^3-1)(x-1)
$$
And it's not difficult to see that this is always positive.

Comment: Since $(x^3-1)(x-1)=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)^2$. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ParasKhosla Sure. I was thinking more "$x-1$ and $x^3-1$ always have the same sign", but your way works too.